# Does a strongly convex function in multiple variables have a "contraction" property?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Contraction is probably a bad term but I mean the following property: if $f(x)$ is $\lambda$-strongly convex and $x^*$ is its minimizer, then for all $x$ we have $\|x-x^*\|^2\leq \frac{2}{\lambda}(f(x)-f(x^*))$. What you get is that if the function value is close to the minimum, then the variables are also close.

I'm wondering what if $f(x,y)$ is strongly convex in $x$ and $y$, that is, for any $x$, $f(x,\cdot)$ is strongly convex and same hold for any fixed $y$ (but not necessarily jointly convex)? Say I find $x,y$ s.t $f(x,y)\leq f(x^*,y^*)+\epsilon$, where $(x^*,y^*)$ minimizes $f$. Can we say anything about $x$ being close to $x^*$ or $y$ being close to $y^*$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. The contraction property is a direct consequence of strong convexity. Specifically, from the first order character of strongly convex functions:
$$f(\mathbf{y})\geq f(\mathbf{x})+\partial f(\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|^2.
$$
Without strong convexity, there is no contraction. Furthermore, convexity in individual coordinates might sound like a "nice" property, however it's almost meaningless from the perspective of convex analysis. Think of the function
$$f(x,y) = x^22^{y^2+1}$$
which is strongly convex for $x,y$ separately, but is a completely messy function otherwise.